# UITextView work wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I have a Chat screen which have a `UITextView` and it can save the text value when user input (Although I go to another view and then back to the chat screen, and the text value which input by user also saved; text value in TextView just nil when user click send button).
 When I make a call (it means I go to the call screen into my app, not related to the call screen of OS) and then press end call to back to the Chat screen. 
The problem is the text value of `UITextView` is nil and rarely, it just save the first letter of the long text. I don't clear text any where. Please help me to explain why?

Comment: show us your source code :-)

Comment: to show the chat screen you are calling popToViewContrroller or pushToViewController? if you are calling pushToViewController, no value will be retained

Comment: i think the problem is line number 4 in your code. :)

Comment: When you show some code then include your viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods if you implemented them.